# Loading iOS app resources from a website

Tags: ios, runtime, loading, assets, nsbundle

I'm currently working on an universal iOS application which has reached more than 100mb in size due to the heavy usage of video and sound files. I've implemented a solution for loading these assets at runtime (from a website) but I'd like to know if Apple approves of such actions.

The way it works now is this:

1. A bundle (with all the video and sound files) is created for each iOS device type: iPhone, iPhone Retina and iPad.
2. Then this bundle is zipped and uploaded to the server.
3. Depending on what device the app is installed on, the corresponding zip file is downloaded, saved to the Documents directory and then unzipped.
4. Finally the bundle is loaded with [NSBundle bundleWithPath: ]

This method works fine but I couldn't figure out by reading the docs if Apple may reject the app because of it? Thanks!

Comment: I like your solution! Why don't you just try it? Apple also "just" tracked their iPhone users, so why should you bother ;)

Answer (score 1):

As long you are just moving around audio and video files, Apple won't have a problem.

But I would suggest (for the user's sake) breaking up the package a bit further so that the user doesn't have to suffer a 100MB download.

Perhaps include a few files so that users w/o internet can do something with your app.

Comment: Actually 100mb is the total size of the assets (iPad + iPhone + iPhone Retina files). Sounds are the same for every device only the videos are different (by resolution and aspect ratio). So for example if the app is installed on an iPhone only these type of videos are downloaded (around 25 mb) not the whole 100mb of data.